# in R function, assign data frame object as a name? loop through function

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

My question is two fold. First, given these three data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(k1 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
             k2 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
             k3 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
             k4 = runif(6, min=0, max=100))
df2 <- data.frame(k1 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
              k2 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
              k3 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
              k4 = runif(6, min=0, max=100))
df3 <- data.frame(k1 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
              k2 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
              k3 = runif(6, min=0, max=100), 
              k4 = runif(6, min=0, max=100))
```

I would like to reformat and rename part of each data frame using this function:

```
samplelist<-c("k2", "k4")

draft_fxn<-function(x, obj_name){
  x.selected<-x[,c(samplelist)] #select columns of choice
  colnames(x.selected)[1:2]<-paste(obj_name, colnames(x.selected), sep="_") #rename columns so they include original data frame name
  return(x.selected)
}

#Example run and output:
df2_final<-draft_fxn(df2, "df2")
#output from:
head(df2_final[1:2],)
>     df2_k2   df2_k4
>1  5.240274 53.03423
>2  5.042926 34.78974
```

First question: How can I change my function so I don't have to type in ' df2, "df2" '. In my draft_fxn code, I want to replace "obj_name" with whatever the name of the input data frame is. In my example it is "df2".

Second question: How can I loop through all of my data frames? Perhaps, similar to this for loop?
    objs<-c(df1, df2, df3)

```
for (file in objs){
  out<-draft_fxn(file); return(out)
} #this doesn't work though.
```

Comment: You would probably be better off [keeping a list of data.frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) from the beginning rather than having a bunch of loosely related variables lying around with data in the variable name itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question: you can obtain the name of an object `x` using `deparse(substitute(x))`. So to eliminate the argument `obj_name` from your function, you could use

```
draft_fxn <- function(x){
    obj_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    x.selected<-x[,c(samplelist)]
    colnames(x.selected)[1:2]<-paste(obj_name, colnames(x.selected), sep="_") #rename columns so they include original data frame name
    return(x.selected)
}
```

As to your second question, if you wanted to perform such an operation for multiple data frames, you would usually put them in a list and then `lapply` the function. In this case, however, it does not work, because the object name changes if you put the data frames into a list, i.e. `deparse(substitute(x))` returns `X[[i]]_`instead of the name of the individual data frame. If you wanted to do it in a loop I would suggest a different approach where you pass a vector of the names of the data frames:

```
## Names of the relevant data frames:
objNames <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
## Function to rename the specified columns:
renameFun <- function(xString){
    x <- get(xString)[,c(samplelist)]
    colnames(x) <- paste(xString, samplelist, sep = "_")
    x   
}

## Apply function to all data frames specifed by objNames:
lapply(objNames, renameFun) 
# [[1]]
#      df1_k2    df1_k4
# 1 54.232123  2.178375
# 2 16.816784 23.586760
# 3  6.612874 16.509340
# 4 92.399588 71.133637
# 5 22.917838  8.127079
# 6 43.563411 21.118758
# 
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

So your function is not well-specified because you're defining `samplelist` outside of the function and then calling it inside. The problem with that is that if you don't have `samplelist` defined, the function will return an error, i.e. it's not self-contained.

Here's an alternative:

```
  draft_fxn<-function(x, cols =...){
  x.selected<-data.frame(x[, cols]) #select columns of choice
  colnames(x.selected)<-paste(deparse(substitute(x)), colnames(x.selected), sep="_") #rename columns so they include original data frame name
  return(x.selected)
}
```

Note that the `cols` argument can vary (as long as it's positive and not larger than the number of columns in your data frame).

This returns:

```
> df2_final<- draft_fxn(df2, cols = c("k2", "k4"))
> head(df2_final)[1:2,]
    df2_k2    df2_k4
1 21.62533  2.256182
2 64.83556 67.705705
```